# supertest e2e with nestjs: request is not a function

Tags: node.js, e2e-testing, supertest, nestjs

I try to introduce e2e tests for my simple NestJS backend services. I am providing a custom userService and a custom UserRepository mocked with sinon.

This is my **user.e2e-spec.ts** file:

```js
import * as request from 'supertest';
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from '../../src/user/user.service';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from '../../src/user/user.entity';
import { TestUtil } from '../../src/utils/TestUtil';
import { createFakeUser } from '../../src/user/test/userTestUtil';

let sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox;
let testUtil;

describe('User', () => {
    let app: INestApplication;
    const fakeUser = createFakeUser();
    const userService = { findOne: () => fakeUser };

    beforeAll(async () => {
        sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
        testUtil = new TestUtil(sandbox);
        const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: UserService,
                    useValue: userService,
                },
                {
                    provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
                    useValue: testUtil.getMockRepository().object,
                },
            ],
        }).compile();

        app = module.createNestApplication();
        await app.init();
    });

    it(`/GET user`, () => {
        return request(app.getHttpServer())
            .get('/user/:id')
            .expect(200)
            .expect({
                data: userService.findOne(),
            });
    });

    afterAll(async () => {
        await app.close();
    });
});
```

and this is my **user.controller.ts**:

```ts
import { ApiBearerAuth, ApiUseTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Controller, Get, Param } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@ApiUseTags('Users')
@ApiBearerAuth()
@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
    constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}

    @Get('/:id')
    findOne(@Param('id') id: number): Promise<User> {
        return this.userService.find(id);
    }
}
```

I wrote a bunch of Unit tests with the same pattern and it works. Have no clue what is wrong with this e2e supertest.

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**:
This is the error message I get:

```
TypeError: request is not a function
    at Object.it (/Users/florian/Development/Houzy/nestjs-backend/e2e/user/user.e2e-spec.ts:40:16)
    at Object.asyncFn (/Users/florian/Development/Houzy/nestjs-backend/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine_async.js:124:345)
    at resolve (/Users/florian/Development/Houzy/nestjs-backend/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queue_runner.js:46:12)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at mapper (/Users/florian/Development/Houzy/nestjs-backend/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queue_runner.js:34:499)
    at promise.then (/Users/florian/Development/Houzy/nestjs-backend/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queue_runner.js:74:39)
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: Also, include more info. Such as error message, what you have tried etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change import of request to:

```
import request from 'supertest';
```

In your test, replace :id with number:

```
it(`/GET user`, () => {
        return request(app.getHttpServer())
            .get('/user/1') // pass here id, not a string
            .expect(200)
            .expect({
                data: userService.findOne(),
        });
});
```

And in controller:

```
 @Get('/:id')
    findOne(@Param('id') id: number): Promise<User> {
        return this.userService.find(id);
 }
```

This should work now.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I still get the same error.

Comment: @FlorianRüegg changed answer. Update your request import in tests.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem!